# Initialise std::string in uninitialised, unowned memory

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using a C library (libwebsockets) which allows some user-data for each client. The library owns this memory, passes it as a `void*`, and my code `reinterpret_cast`'s it to my user-data type.

I'm trying to add a `std::string` field to this class and am now seeing segfaults. Calling functions on this class causes errors, which is fair enough as it's likely backed by uninitialised memory.

How can I initialise that memory> I've tried assigning (the assignment operator segfaults) and calling various functions such as `clear`. I'm guessing there's a C++ mechanism for this.

Furthermore, how can the destructor be called when the string is no longer needed?

Comment: If the memory pointed to by the `void *` wasn't allocated as an object of the type you are casting it to, then of course the memory won't be initialized.  It's a bit unclear who is making this heap allocation and how they did it; that's an important part of this question.

Comment: @cdhowie, libwebsockets allocates the memory per-client. I just tell it how many bytes I need for each client, and it gives me a `void*` when a client connects, then in each callback. In some APIs I've seen this referred to as a closure.

Comment: If you want to initialize allocated-only memory, try `placement new`

Comment: @Erbureth, cheers, I found this just a minute ago online and it seems to work for the initialisation. Is there an equivalent operation for destroying the instance when done?

Comment: @DrewNoakes Yes, you can call the destructor directly: `ptr->~NameOfType()`

Comment: Wow, the C++ tag on SO is populated with downvoting trolls who don't provide any constructive rationale. I really don't care about downvotes, but it creates a much less inclusive sub-community compared to that of other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a type something like this:

```
class MyType
{
    std::string foo;
    std::string bar;
};
```

And assuming that the `void *` points to an uninitialized allocation of at least `sizeof(MyType)` bytes, then you can construct it (and all contained objects) using placement new syntax:

```
void init_callback(void * ptr) {
    new (ptr) MyType();
}
```

Similarly, you can destruct your type (which will destruct all contained objects) by calling the destructor directly.

```
void destroy_callback(void * ptr) {
    MyType * mine = reinterpret_cast<MyType *>(ptr);
    mine->~MyType();
}
```

Generally you don't call destructors directly, but you have to because you can't safely `delete` the pointer.  The rule "every `new` should have one `delete`" has an analog in this situation: "every placement-new should have one explicit call to the destructor."

Comment: Just wanted to report back and say that this approach produced clean, comprehensible code that even works :) Thanks again.

Comment: Why cast *before* `new`?

Comment: @Yakk Indeed, it is unnecessary. I was thinking of the destructor case when writing it and forgot to go back to edit it. At least it doesn't *hurt* and it shouldn't cause any change to code-gen since it can all be optimized away.

Answer (score 1):

You can use placement-new to create an object in the provided memory:

```
std::string * s = new(memory) std::string;
```

and call the destructor to destroy it before reusing or releasing the memory:

```
s->std::string::~string();
```

If you find that a bit of a mouthful, then `using std::string;` will reduce it to `s->~string();`

Comment: @NeilKirk it does without `decltype`.. Just template it.  I added that as an answer to show how it can be done with `unique_ptr`.